# Alexa / Lex Intent design for adjusting numeric value

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

I'm unsure how to model an Alexa skill that involves **adjusting numeric parameters** and should **allow both relative and absolute adjustments**.

Utterances could be similar to:

- Set temperature to 20 degrees
- Raise temperature by 2 degrees
- Increase the temperature to 25 degrees
- etc.

**Idea 1: Create separate intents for *increase*, *decrease*, and *set***

The utterances of these three are going to be nearly identical which is against recommended best practices.

**Idea 2: One intent containing a *{AdjustmentType}* Slot**

That *{AdjustmentType}* slot would contain the values *increase*|*decrease*|*set* and according aliases. This way I'd no longer have multiple intents with very similar utterances but I would additionally need to deal with *to* and *by* who change the meaning and basically overrule *{AdjustmentType}*. I could simply create another slot type for this and deal with it using Lambda. I'm wondering though whether this is really the way to go as I would end up having utterances that contain little more than slots.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As {AdjustmentType} is your on slot type the better solution would be to create custom slots for AdjustmentType. You can have multiple utterences for a given intent. It means even if you have only one intent you can configure multiple sample utterences and it will invoke those utterences based on your voice input.

Comment: This only works as long as I don't add another intent for returning the current value (e.g. a "getter" intent). If I do this, alexa always detects the getter intent, even if the utterance exactly matches one of the sample setter utterances.
Of course, I can also integrate that one into one single intent, but honestly, that can hardly be the solution, because otherwise I could as well process the utterance myself.

Comment: I ended up using just one intent for setting (absolute and relative) and getting values. Additionally I figured out that in contrast to Amazon Alexa, Microsoft LUIS provides some advanced features for dealing with dependencies between slots.